# Need help finding only Employees and Sales Persons in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ebs

I am trying to run an SQL query which would fetch me all people who are
1. Only employees, 
2. Employees and a sales person and 
3. Only sales persons. 
I am working on the Oracle E-Business Suite. So far, my query returns only those people who are employees only and those people who are employees and also a sales person. Here is what I've managed so far:

```
select distinct PAF.LAST_NAME,
  PAF.START_DATE "HIRE_DATE",
  PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
  PPT.SYSTEM_PERSON_TYPE "PERSON_TYPE",
  JRS.SALES_CREDIT_TYPE_ID,
  JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER
from PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAF,
  PER_PERSON_TYPES PPT,
  PER_PERSON_TYPE_USAGES_F PPTU,
  JTF_RS_DEFRESOURCES_VL JRDV,
  JTF_RS_SALESREPS JRS
where PAF.PERSON_ID          = PPTU.PERSON_ID                
and PPTU.PERSON_TYPE_ID      = PPT.PERSON_TYPE_ID             
and PPT.SYSTEM_PERSON_TYPE  in ('EMP','OTHER')
and JRDV.category           in ('EMPLOYEE','OTHER')
and (JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER(+) = PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER)
and sysdate between PAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and PAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE;
```

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hEJm.jpg)

I have to include those people who are ONLY salespersons. Basically, there should be some rows which have no Employee_Number but only SALESREP_NUMBER. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello! Please read [how to write a minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and simplify your example if possible. Also, it would be great to have the structure of your tables to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @brclz I apologize. I should've posted only the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your issue lies here:

```
AND PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER      = JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER
```

Like the comment above says, you don't give much info. But, an educated guess would be that the equivalence indicated above would make that person an employee AND a salesperson. Maybe something more like:

```
AND (
    PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER      = JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER
    OR
    ( PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AND JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER IS NULL)
    OR
    ( PAF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER IS NULL AND JRS.SALESREP_NUMBER)
)
```

Or maybe just delete that clause?

Comment: I removed that clause. Can you please have a look into this again?

Comment: You removed that clause.... and what happened? Nothing? Did it work? The above was about as far as I could go with limited info. You would do well to reread the first comment on your original post.

Comment: After removing the clause, I now get people who are both employees and salespersons. I still need to get the people who are only employees alongwith those who are both employees and salespersons.

Comment: Also after searching and reading, I'm considering using a Union to join these two conditions separately. Is my understanding correct? Can you please advice? I'll try to share the table details tomorrow.

Comment: Have you heard of a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes, I have but I'm still new at this. Can you please explain?

Comment: You understand a default join gives rows with entries in both tables? A left join returns rows from left table without matches in the right. But a union is a good idea here as well, as long as your columns match up.

Really, it might be best to just select all from both tables and create a column using a CASE statement that indicates their status as one or the other or both.

Comment: Which two tables exactly are you suggesting? I understand the Case technique you mentioned. I'm sorry if I sound very naive.

Comment: Vaguely, looking at your table list, I would suggest selecting from the all people table, and use subqueries to make boolean columns denoting status, like "employee", and "salesrep". 

This is just logic, and there's more than one way to do it. You just need a clear idea of what data you need and where it is. I'm not that clear on that - you need to be.

Comment: As you suggested, using Left Join helped in fetching people who are employees only and both employees and salespersons. But I still need people who act as only salespersons. I've modified the original post to include the latest query.

Comment: UNION the salesreps table?

Comment: That would require me to use Null as a column name for many columns of the Salesreps table. To avoid that, I'm still trying to figure this out in a single query if that's possible. I really appreciate the efforts @Rob Wood.

Comment: A UNION is technically still a single query. But I still think a full grab of the users and then a field subquery or two to get status is your best bet.